# Updating the same record after insert within the same commit/unit-of-work

Tags: sql, database, db2

Most likely a stupid question, but from what I know I should be able to update (with standard dml update statement) a record after I inserted it with before (with standard insert statement)?

e.g.
Program A:

```
(do some stuff)
INSERT (keyfield1=1,...) into X
(do some more stuff)
IF something-changed-in-record-data
   UPDATE X (set keyfield1=1, other fields/values..) WHERE keyfield1=1
(do other stuff)
COMMIT/SYNCPOINT
```

After doing so, I keep getting sqlcode 100 (not found).

I'm confused about why this doesn't work.

PS:
Yes, I can change the processing logic and do the insert at the end, but the logic is rather complex to do that in a fast way.

Comment: Might be helpful to know what kind of language/framework is used by "Program A" to issue SQL statements... Generally, debugging pseudo-code is futile.

Comment: I'd change program to insert at the end.  Less IO makes sense for a faster program.  The actual problem is you can't updated an uncommitted record?

Comment: Are you trying to update the primary key value? If yes, then look at the update statement. You have keyfield in WHERE clause, If you update that keyfield value then you won't find any row satisfying the WHERE clause. This will be contradictory.

Comment: Try to change the WHERE clause to point to the same inserted row and use some non-key column in the WHERE clause. If that works, then you know you can't update the key value using the same key value in WHERE clause of Update statement.

Comment: No, updated fields are non-key fields and are not in any indexes. yes. to change the processing logic to make the insert as last action before the commit is the last way we are looking for, because this will need a massive change of the program logic. The program is running on z/os, cics, cobol and ibm DB2. But the development is done with MFE (Microfocus Mainframe Express), which is basically simulation of a z/os mainframe, except for the database, which is connected directly to the db2 server.

Comment: just for fun and testing i changed the update to an insert statement and i got an duplicate key error. so thats even more confusing.

Comment: You need to be more specific about your INSERT and UPDATE statements. What you have written above is that you are Inserting keyfield=1 and then doing an update for keyfield with value as 1 using the same in the WHERE clause as keyfield=1. Since the computers don't make mistakes and there is No magic happening in the world, I would believe the UPDATE statement that it could not find what you think it would. So, you would need to post the actual INSERT and UPDATE statements that you are using.

Comment: Are you working with a connection pool, where the insert and update may be occurring in different contexts?